# Python `beautifulsoup` extraction on urls lacking `class`, other attributes?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Quick question [I am not very familiar with Python's `BeautifulSoup()`]  If I have the following element,

how can I extract/get "1 comment" (or, "2 comments", etc.)?  There is no `class` (or `id`, or other attributes) in that "`a`" tag.

```html
<td class="subtext">
  <a href="item?id=22823679">1&nbsp;comment</a>
</td>
```

Comment: the `a` tag is a child of `subtext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How about the following, test with local `html` file*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "D:\\Temp\\example.html"

with open(url, "r") as page:
    contents = page.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')
    element = soup.select('td.subtext')
    value = element[0].get_text()
    print(value)
```

---

*example.html*

```
<html>
    <head></head>
        <body>
            <td class="subtext">
                <a href="item?id=22823679">1&nbsp;comment</a>
            </td>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very nice.  I am writing a script to parse HackerNews articles according to votes and presence of comments; the latter attribute was tripping me up.  I'll post a GitHub link, once I finish it. Much appreciated, thank you! Bonus: working with local files! :-)

Comment: Very interesting, do share the link- good luck @VictoriaStuart

Comment: I will ... there is so much noise in that group: I want to filter out {low-impact  | dead | Wikipedia links with no comments | ditto, re: Youtube | ...} distractions.

Comment: @ 0m3r -- as promised: https://github.com/victoriastuart/hacker_news_scraper

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select` method to apply a querySelect into your html, and then take the `contents` of the elements you found:

```
elements = soup.select(".subtext a")
[x.contents for x in elements]
```

Comment: This is also an excellent answer (thank you!); noted for future reference!